# Returning values outside of a function

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have a function which gets some values from Google analytics and prints them to the screen. I need to use these values later on in the file. When i try to assign these values to a variable it is null but the print is displaying the values correctly. An example of the values being printed is 
3188, 2530, 2475, 1340, 2184.

```
  function printResults($reports){
global $anna;
for ($j = 0; $j < count($metrics); $j++) {
              $values = $metrics[$j]->getValues();
              for ($k = 0; $k < count($values); $k++) {
                  $entry = $metricHeaders[$k];
                  print($values[$k] . ", ");
                  $anna.=$values[$k]. ", ";
              }
          }
}
```

So the vaules correctly display using the print but when i try to echo the variable $anna outside of the function it does not.

Ok so after looking at the solution from Don't Panic it became obvious that the variable just needed to be returned. Who would have thought it :) Thanks for the help!

```
for ($j = 0; $j < count($metrics); $j++) {
              $values = $metrics[$j]->getValues();
              for ($k = 0; $k < count($values); $k++) {
                  $entry = $metricHeaders[$k];
                  //print($values[$k] . ", ");
                  $anna.=$values[$k]. ", ";
                  return $anna;
              }
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Thanks for the link. have set $anna as global at start of function and it only returns a partial result. the print is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 where as $anna only contains 4,5

Comment: Where does `$metrics` come from?

Comment: There is some code before that it is to select what metrics you want from analytics such as sessions, page views, time on site etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a different approach. It looks like your function gets all the values from a set of metrics that each contains a set of values, and prints them. If you need to use the set of values, then your function that directly prints them isn't as useful. Make a function that just gets the values and returns them in an array. *Be sure to `return` them!*

```
function getAllValues($metrics) {
    foreach ($metrics as $metric) {
        foreach ($metric->getValues() as $value) {
            $allValues[] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $allValues;
}
```

<sub>I'm assuming the `$reports` argument in the example in your question is supposed to be `$metrics`.</sub>

Then, you can call this function to get your values.

```
$values = getAllValues($metrics);
```

And if you need to print them, just

```
echo implode(', ', $values);
```

That way your function does what it says it does.

Comment: The code used is from the google developers site but i do think your way is perfect for what i want to achieve so will give that a try! I need to get it to play nicely with the google analytics function though.

Comment: I am using most of the code from this page. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php What I am trying to do though is plot a chart for each day of the month so am doing a loop and getting the value for each day and assigning the number to the $anna variable to then output in the format the chart requires (1,2,3,4...)